# Making an embedded iframe ignore swipe event

Tags: javascript, iframe, webkit, scroll, swipe-gesture

I have a page with an iframe that takes up most of the width of my page when viewed on a mobile device.

In my particular case, this iframe holds a scene7 html5 player from adobe.

The problem is that this page on an iphone is nearly impossible to scroll, as the when the user swipes, the iframe seems to capture that swipe event.

I see lots of issues around the web where people are trying to get overflowed divs or iframes to recognize swipes and scrolls, but my problem is the opposite.

I want to prevent the iframe from intercepting or terminating my swipe or drag, so that the user can scroll the parent page easily and get to content that lies further down the page, below my iframe.

Is there a general solution to this problem?

Comment: Try event.preventDefault on swipe events, then